# Im trying to install Magento via composer can't insert password

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username: d89125c***********************
      Password:
```

when it comes to **password** I can't type or paste the password:

I'm new in magento am i missing anything ?

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 5):

When you enter the password (typed or pasted), you won't get any feedback. This is common for command line applications.

You can still paste or type your password, then press enter. It should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy paste the private key as password. It will work.

Comment: The labels and lack of info in the docs confused me: the public key is the Username and the private key is the Password...usually the private key is kept "private" and not shared in such a manner.

Answer (score 0):

passsword wil be invisible .. pls paste password one tym n give enter ..